# Script to align text in Google Sheets script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to align text top left with all fields wrapping in a Google worksheet as it loses formatting whenever the form response propogates it. I managed to find a script that fixed the wrapping side of things within script edit but I can't work out how to align text to the top of all table cells. Here is the script I am trying to use.

```
function wrap(e) {
  e.range.setWrap(true);
  e.range.setVerticalAlignment(DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.TOP);
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the wrong 'service. If you are working with a spreadsheet you'd use

```
e.range.setVerticalAlignment("top")
```